# cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable - I get this error when not using Comparable

Tags: java, arrays, comparable

Here is the code that the program breaks on (second line, `Arrays.sort`):

```
public void check3Kind(){       
    Arrays.sort(YahtzeeGUI.getGame().getDice()); //sorts the array so i can check for identical numbers in order

    int dice0 = YahtzeeGUI.getGame().getDice(0).getFaceValue();
    int dice1 = YahtzeeGUI.getGame().getDice(1).getFaceValue();
    int dice2 = YahtzeeGUI.getGame().getDice(2).getFaceValue();
    int dice3 = YahtzeeGUI.getGame().getDice(3).getFaceValue();
    int dice4 = YahtzeeGUI.getGame().getDice(4).getFaceValue();

    int score = + dice0 + dice1 + dice2 + dice3 + dice4;

    if ( (dice0 == dice1 && dice0 == dice2) || (dice1 == dice2 && dice1 == dice3) || (dice2 == dice3 && dice2 == dice4)){
        YahtzeeGUI.setBtnScore(11, score);
    }
}
```

It spits out this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: Dice cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at Scoring.check3Kind(Scoring.java:84)
at YahtzeeGUI$RollHandler.actionPerformed(YahtzeeGUI.java:235)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I think it's something to do with sorting the array, but I'm not too sure. I've never used Comparable and don't really understand how to use it in this context

Get Game:

```
private static Yahtzee y = new Yahtzee();

public static Yahtzee getGame(){
    return y;
}
```

Get Dice:

```
private Dice[] dice = new Dice[5];

public Dice[] getDice(){
    return dice;
}
```

Comment: How are you expecting the sort to happen? Does your `Dice` class implement `Comparable<Dice>`? You have to tell Java how to compare your custom types.

Comment: you need to have a comparator for Dice, and call Arrays.sort(YahtzeeGUI.getGame().getDice(), new MyCmp);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Arrays.sort(Object[]) will try to cast object to Comparable and use them for sorting algorithm.

In order to make sorting happen, you need the following:

```
public class DiceComparator implements Comparator<Dice>{
    @Override
    public int compare(final Dice o1, final Dice o2) {
        //here comes logic for comparison
        return 0;
    }
}

Arrays.sort(YahtzeeGUI.getGame().getDice(), new DiceComparator());
```

Another possibility to let Dice implement Comparable

```
public class Dice implements Comparable<Dice>{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Dice o) {
        //here comes logic for comparison
        return 0;
    }
}

Arrays.sort(YahtzeeGUI.getGame().getDice());
```

Comment: No. Comparable interface doesn't have this method.

Answer (score 1):

For Java to be able to sort a collection of your custom objects, it needs to know what rules to use for deciding on the order of 2 objects of that class. For example, suppose your class `Dice` was:

```
public class Dice {
    private int foo;
    private int bar;
    // getters / setters   
}
```

If you wanted to do `Arrays.sort(diceList)`, and say `diceList` had two `Dice` objects `dice1` (foo = 5; bar = 10), and `dice2` (foo = 7; bar = 3), how will they be sorted?

So, you need to tell Java how to sort them. For this, either your class `Dice` needs to implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, or you need to create a separate [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) class to do the sorting based on some logic. Example for `Comparable`:

```
public class Dice implements Comparable<Dice> {
    private int foo;
    private int bar;
    // getters / setters
    public int compareTo(Dice dice) {
        if (dice == null || this.foo == dice.foo) {
            return 0;
        } else if (this.foo > dice.foo) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This way when you call `Arrays.sort(diceList)`, it knows that it has to sort them based on just the `foo` property. In our example, since `dice2.foo` > `dice1.foo`, after sorting, the list will contain `dice2` before `dice1` in the list.

I encourage you to go through the javadocs for `Comparable` and `Comparator`. What you see here is just the tip of the iceberg! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make these corrections in your code as follows :

```
int dice0 = YahtzeeGUI.getGame().getDice()[0].getFaceValue();
    int dice1 = YahtzeeGUI.getGame().getDice()[1].getFaceValue();
    int dice2 = YahtzeeGUI.getGame().getDice()[2].getFaceValue();
    int dice3 = YahtzeeGUI.getGame().getDice()[3].getFaceValue();
    int dice4 = YahtzeeGUI.getGame().getDice()[4].getFaceValue();
```

And, implement `java.lang.Comparable` interface in your `Dice` class.